# Monkeyrunner error for some real devices

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

the code is very simple

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.touch(84, 712, "DOWN_AND_UP")
```

It's OK to run on simulator and my SE Xperia Ray,

but when I run on another device ,which is not sell on the market.

error messages pop out.

It's ok to run some commands, for example, take "snapShot"

but for "touch" "press", always failed.

is it some monkeyruuner bugs that for some devices, it just not worked

or the problem is on the devices, that maybe the modified device source code have some issue.

I had search on the internet, and can't find solution for this,

And I need to decide to use monkeyruuner on the devices or not,

So, I need some help.

sorry for my English : )

the error log is

```
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error se
nding touch event: 84 712 DOWN_AND_UP
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]java.net.
SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.n
io.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.n
io.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.n
io.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:276)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.n
io.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:236)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.chimpchat.ChimpManager.sendMonkeyEventAndGetResponse(ChimpManager.java:18
6)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.chimpchat.ChimpManager.sendMonkeyEvent(ChimpManager.java:234)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.chimpchat.ChimpManager.tap(ChimpManager.java:329)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.touch(AdbChimpDevice.java:361)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice.touch(MonkeyDevice.java:136)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.r
eflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.r
eflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.r
eflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:175)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:355)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:432)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:436)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.pycode._pyx0.f$0(d:\1234.py:18)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.pycode._pyx0.call_function(d:\1234.py)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.p
ython.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)
121129 10:56:42.227:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.a
ndroid.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)
```

Comment: Do the device and firmware pass CTS tests?

Comment: Hi dtmilano, Yes, the device and firmware pass CTS tests

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in obtaining the connection

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
```

and unfortunately device is never `None`, so to verify it, you can take the same approach as [ViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) does, using this snippet

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
try:
        device.wake()
except java.lang.NullPointerException, e:
        print >> sys.stderr, "%s: ERROR: Couldn't connect to %s: %s" % (progname, serialno, e)
        sys.exit(3)
```

Comment: Hi,
After I run the code I got,
121206 14:36:20.494:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Unable to wake device (too sleepy?)
121206 14:36:20.494:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
...
...

and, the except is not printing messages

Comment: Finding the root cause may require an investigation of your device and firmware. As you mentioned already, it doesn't happen on emulator or Sony Xperia.